# How to control verbosity in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

In TensorFlow 1.x I had great freedom in choosing how and when to print accuracy/loss scores during training. Fore example, if I wanted to print training loss every 100 epochs, in a `tf.Session()` I'd write:

```
if epoch % 100 == 0:
    print(str(epoch) + '. Training Loss: ' + str(loss))
```

After the release of TF 2.0 (alpha), it seems that the Keras API forces to stick with its standard output. Is there a way to take that flexibility back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use the Keras Model methods (`.fit`, `.train_on_batch`, ...) and you write your own training loop using eager execution (and optionally wrapping it in a `tf.function` to convert it in its graph representation) you can control the verbosity as you're used to do in 1.x

```
training_epochs = 10
step = 0
for epoch in range(training_epochs)
    print("starting ",epoch)
    for features, labels in dataset:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = compute_loss(model(features),labels)
        gradients = tape.gradients(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        step += 1
        if step % 10 == 0:
            # measure other metrics if needed
            print("loss: ", loss)
    print("Epoch ", epoch, " finished.")
```

Comment: That's great. I have additional questions: 1) Where is the `compute_loss()` function coming from?; 2) Should lines 5 and 6 be within the `with` block?; 3) Where can I control the number of epochs? Thank you! (Grazie!)

Comment: `compute_loss` is just pseudocode. Substitute it with your loss (coming from tf.keras.losses if possible).

No, the 5 and 6 lines can be outside the gradient tape. The tape is used only to register the actions (and you executed the forward pass invoking model and the loss computation).

Since you're iterating a dataset, you can control the epochs in many different ways: manually, knowing the dataset size. Or if the `dataset` is a `tf.data.Dataset` object then you can use the `.repeat(n)` method to make the dataset repeat for n epochs

Comment: On line 2: `for input in dataset`. Is `dataset` a numpy object? And if so, it seems it's taking one line at a time like in Stochastic GD. If I wanted to implement simple GD, can I write: `for epoch in range(num_epochs):` and put my `Dataset` instead of input? Thanks

Comment: dataset is something iterable. Look at how `tf.data.Dataset` documentation (but it can be even numpy). To implement a simple training loop, look at this example https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/eager#variables_and_optimizers .
However, yes, you can do something like 'for epoch in range(num_epochs)` with inside another loop that iterates over the dataset once

Comment: Sorry, it's not completely clear why I would need a second nested loop with a unique iteration. Couldn't I just put some np.array to your `input` object ?

Comment: I updated the example - have a look. Btw dataset is an iterable, you can make it return whatever you want. In my case I suppose it returns the pair `(features, labels)`

Comment: @Leevo if my answer helped you in solving your problem please remember to mark it as accepted!